# How to hide/collapse the Build window when gradle syncs successfully in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, is there a way to make the Build tab only pop up when there are warnings or errors, and not when the syncing is successful?

Comment: Looks like it is not configurable for Android Studio. In IntelliJ IDEA if you hide it and there are no errors in re-import (from Gradle tool window) - it will be shown only if there are errors. but the Android Studio sync always pops up the tool window. Feel free to file a request at https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs